# Clicking element unreliable when making changes in editor and using auto-rerun or manually rerunning

Tags: cypress

I'm performing a standard `click()` on a search bar that has a tooltip on hover. When launching a fresh Test Runner or simply replaying my test without code changes, all works well; 100% of the time I get a successful click.

When I make a code change and rerun automatically or by manually triggering a rerun without relaunching the Test Runner, I most often (near 100%? I've not done exhaustive testing) only seem to get the hover behavior (the tooltip displays).

I've attempted a `should('be.visible')` before the click, `dblClick()`, `click().click()`, and `trigger('click')` to no avail.

Mouse Events for the command show the exact same things firing on the exact same element (a child `<span>` of the targeted `<button>`).

As this seems entirely related to the Test Runner being reused could it be a caching issue or bug?

Comment: Try [https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-watch-and-reload](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-watch-and-reload). Otherwise, is it a memory overload? I recently had update problems when memory usage was +80%.

Comment: Thanks. Will give it a go and report back.

Answer (score 0):

It may be the click handler is slow to attach in certain condions.

This uses the retry of `.should()` with callback to keep clicking until a condition is met, or timeout.

```js
cy.get('button')
  .should($clickable => {     
    $clickable.click()
    expect(result-of-click).to.equal(expected-result-of-click) 
  })
})
```